# How to use the string properly

Tags: vb6

I want to use the sting in gridcode

Code

```
Dim View as string
View = "Rajan & vbtab & 211"
With gridview
 .AddItem View
End with
```

'
Output (FlexGrid)

```
 Name Value

`Rajan & vbtab & 211`
```

'It is showing in name column, it should show Rajan in name column, 211 in value Column.

What wrong in my code.

Expected Output(FlexGrid)

```
Name Value 

Rajan 211
```

Need code Help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vbtab` is the keyword you have not closed your quotes properly..

```
Dim View as string
View = "Rajan" & vbtab & "211"
With gridview
 .AddItem View
End with
```

The above code should work.

Comment: I want to give vbtab also in string, because i have 50 number of columns, so i cannot able to enter 50 times vbtab, can you please help me....

Comment: u can not give `vbtab` in string, u will have to concatenate is properly

Comment: What about & opeator, whether i have to give in double quotes or not...?

Comment: your `&` operator is for concatenating the strings with your variables it should be outside quotes only.